# How do I calculate the proportion of 2nd and 3rd generation of AA, Aa and aa individuals?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let say I have a population of **AA**, **Aa** and **aa** types.
If propagation is random and independent, and the initial proportions are **AA**:**Aa**:**aa** **p**:**q**:**r**, where **p,q,r** $≥ 0$ and **p+q+r** $=1$.

What would the proportions of the next generation be?

As far as I understand these are the possible mixes:
**AA** $\cap$ **AA** = **p** $\times$ **p**
**AA** $\cap$ **Aa** = **p** $\times$ **q**
**AA** $\cap$ **aa** = **p** $\times$ **r**
**Aa** $\cap$ **Aa** = **q** $\times$ **q**
**aa** $\cap$ **aa** = **r** $\times$ **r**
**Aa** $\cap$ **aa** = **q** $\times$ **r**

But I don't really know how to move on. How can I calculate the proportions of 2nd and 3rd generation?

Comment: Is $AA \cap AA$ a new type? or is $AA \cap AA = AA$? Are you studying dominant and recessive gene?

Comment: I'd assume the result is always: $AA \cap AA = AA$. Yes they are dominant and recessive.

Comment: what about $AA \cap Aa$, do we get $AA$ $75 \%$ of the time and $Aa$ $25 \%$ of the time?

Comment: Yes I would assume so.